# $(x^2-5)$ is not a prime ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

This question might be very naive but I still want to varify if my idea is right, since I am only beginning ring theory.

I have to show $(x^2-5)$ is not a prime ideal of $\mathbb{R}[x]$. My thought is that, $x^2-5$ can be reduced as $x^2-5=(x-\sqrt{5})(x+\sqrt{5})$ for $x-\sqrt{5},x+\sqrt{5}\in\mathbb{R}[x]$ and since neither of them is necessarily in $(x^2-5)$, we have $(x^2-5)$ not a prime ideal.

Is my idea ok?

Comment: The ideal generated by $x^2-5$ is not prime because the element $x^2-5$ is decomposable. However, it may happen in other rings that an element is Not decomposable, yet the ideal generated by it is not prime.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, and you can see that neither $x - \sqrt5$ or $x + \sqrt 5$ is contained in $\mathfrak p =(x^2 -5)$ since they are degree $1$ and $\mathfrak p$ only contains polynomials of degree $\geq 2$ and the zero polynomial

Comment: Would you like to explain why $(x^2-5)$ only contain degree>2 polynomials?

Comment: @Endpoints because $deg(pq) = deg(p) + deg(q)$ if $p,q$ are nonzero polynomials with coefficients in a field. And $q \in (x^2 -5)$ if $q = p*(x^2 -5)$ so $deg(q) = 2 + deg(p)$ if q is nonzero.